# Ruby on Rails 3 in Production does not minify CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, minify

Ruby 2.1 / Rails 3.2 - In production.rb I have:

config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true

The JS file compresses just fine, with no whitespace, comments, or new lines.

The CSS file still has some whitespace, comments, and all the new lines characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a gem to compress your CSS.

In `Gemfile` add the `sass-rails` gem

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

Then in your `config/production.rb` file tell rails to use it.

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

Comment: Worked, with an addition to application.rb of Sprockets::Compressors.register_css_compressor(:scss, 'Sass::Rails::CssCompressor', :require => 'sass/rails/compressor')

Comment: FYI - in Rails 4 this special line isn't needed. Works out of the box with the compressor config attribute.